# Kendo Grid - get correct grid height after expand

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem that I hadn't solve. I want to get CORRECT grid height after expand or collapse and load items. My code is here:
For example: I need to get height 1164(for example) when after expand and get 321 after collapse. But, it give me a value before loading data.

Thank you.

Link : http://dojo.telerik.com/Onora/14

--OR--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy">
    <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                var expanded = {};
                var grid, id;

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                            },
                            pageSize: 6,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },`enter code here`
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        detailInit: detailInit,
                        detailExpand: function(e) {
                           var gridHeight = $("#grid").height();
                                alert("grid expand:"+gridHeight);  
                        },
                        detailCollapse:  function(e) {
                           var gridHeight = $("#grid").height();
                                alert("grid collapse:"+gridHeight);  
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "FirstName",
                                title: "First Name",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "LastName",
                                title: "Last Name",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Country",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "City",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Title"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });

                function detailInit(e) {
                    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            pageSize: 10,
                            filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "OrderID", width: "70px" },
                            { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                            { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "300px" }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if I am not wrong you are trying to set the height of grid when collapsed to (x) and when expanded the height of outer + detail grid to be (y)

Comment: Yes. I try to put dataBound in datail (inner) grid. I get exact size first expand, but when collapse or re-expand the grid, second grid dataBound isn't triggered again.